# Removing a Raphael element causes it to crash sometimes?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a Raphael javascript program, where I have several (dozens, hundreds, whatever) circles written to the page, like so:

```
evo_sprite = paper.circle(evo.x, evo.y, this.evo_size);
```

Each circle has a limited amount of time I want it displayed, after which I want it destroyed so it doesn't slow stuff down.

When I do:

```
evo_sprite.hide();
```

I have no problems, but I know the sprite is still there, and thus still taking up memory.

So I tried:

```
evo_sprite.remove();
```

And got what APPEARED to be the same result (the circle is no longer displayed).

The only problem is that after some amount of time(seems random), my program freezes and I get the error message:

> a1.paper is undefined
>   [Break On This Error] Raphael=(function(){var a=/[, ]+/,aO=/...eturn d;};an.el=ax[aY];return an;})();

Does this make sense to anybody? Am I calling remove incorrectly?  How am I causing Raphael's code (on line 7 of the min file) to break just by calling remove on a circle?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing your code, but it looks like it is the Raphael canvas that isn't being found (I presume that's what a1.paper is).

Are you instantiating your Raphael canvas on document.onload (or $(document).ready with jQuery)? Make sure there aren't any closures in your code that make functions trying to operate outside the scope of a1.paper.

Then go right back to basics - try it with just a few circles to begin with, then 50, then 100. Then try it in different browsers and see whether it stops working in all of them. SVG is quite browser intensive, so creating thousands of circles might make some browsers break.

Comment: I'm instantiating the canvas on document.onload.  I don't think that's really a problem, because I won't see the issue for minutes at a time. I can render new things to the canvas at any point (and hide them), and the canvas is clearly THERE...it just sometimes won't let me remove things from it.

Comment: Okay, going back to basics like you suggested, and realized that I only get the error after removing the last circle...which is weird (it's not like that's the only object on screen, there's squares, too).  Will look further. Wait, no it's every one. Drat.